# Stackdriver similarity in Charts stats view

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I am creating a chart in Stackdriver. I wanted to view its statistics, but I don't know what similarity means. What is the meaning or how is similarity metric measured in Stackdriver charts stats view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of the [Statistics Mode of Metric Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/chart-view-options#using-statistics-mode), the similarity is a real-valued function that quantifies the similarity between two objects. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similarity_measure) you can find more detailed information.

Comment: Great! Thanks @AlbertoVI. I didn't thought that it was that simple. I just have to use the distance formula to get the Similarity between its minimum and maximum value. :)